# Stable point of group action

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

Group $G$ of order $55$ acts on a set $M$ of cardinality $39$. Prove, that there is an element $x \in M$, such that $\forall g \in G$ $gx=x$.

I tried to apply some combinations of Burnside's lemma or Orbit-stabilizer theorem, to compute sizes of stabilizer subgroups but didn't achieve anything.

Comment: Well you should have achieved something by applying the orbit-stabilizer theorem to compute possible orbit sizes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lengths of orbits under $G$ can be $1,5,11,55$. As $M$ cannot have an orbit of length $55$, assume that there are only $a$ orbits of lengths $5$ and $b$ orbits of length $11$. Then $5a+11b=39$. This has no solution in $a,b\ge0$.

Comment: as I understand that we have at least one orbit of length 1, how to show that element containing in it is one we are looking for?

Comment: The orbit of $x$ is $\{gx \mid g \in G \}$, so if the size of the orbit is $1$, since always $1x=x$, all of $G$ must stabilize $x$.